# Keeping jar version numbers in sync between JitPack and other repositories

Tags: maven, jar, versioning, jitpack

I maintain a few Java library projects on GitLab, which I currently build with a GitLab CI workflow and deploy to a GitLab Maven repository. Now I would like to make them available via JitPack while keeping the GitLab Maven repo for a while.

GitLab’s Maven repo, like most of the others out there, uses the contents of the `<version>` tag in `pom.xml` for versioning. JitPack, on the other hand, needs a Git ref to work with (a branch name, a tag or a plain hash). I am looking for a way to use the same versioning regardless of the repo, so that version `FOO` will fetch a jar based on the same code, regardless of whether it is taken from GitLab or JitPack.

For a released, stable version that could be solved by tagging each release with its version number. That is, when I release version 3.7.0, I would ensure the `<version>` tag in my `pom.xml` reads `3.7.0`, and tag the commit with `3.7.0` as well. I would need to enforce a match between the two (e.g. by teaching CI to bar{k|f} upon detecting a discrepancy), but with some homework, both repos would carry the same version of my code under the same version number.

Things get tricky when it comes to unstable versions. If I am working on the upcoming 3.7.2 release and would already like to make it available for testing, I understand common practice is to set the version tag to `3.7.2-SNAPSHOT`, telling everyone that this is not a stable version. The GitLab Maven repo would serve the jar under that version.

For JitPack, versions ending in `-SNAPSHOT` indicate that the code could have changed since the last build and the jar should be rebuilt from source. A version named `3.7.2-SNAPSHOT` would cause JitPack to look for a ref named `3.7.2` (tag or branch) and build it from scratch.

So I would have to ensure that the version name of the upcoming version resolves to the latest commit for the upcoming version. I could do that by developing the upcoming version in a branch named like the version, but that would presumably result in a naming conflict as I release it, as I would then introduce a tag with the same identifier.

Is there a general recommendation for addressing this, i.e. serving unstable versions of a jar via JitPack and a conventional Maven repo under the same version number?

Comment: One option for unreleased versions that I came up with was using `dev-SNAPSHOT` as the version string (assuming the unstable branch is named `dev`). I understand Maven would accept that as a version string; I am just not sure about version sort order: I would want `dev-SNAPSHOT` to be considered more recent than any released version à la `3.7.0`. On the other hand, when e.g. a gradle project requests `3.7.+` or the like, I would want the repo to serve a stable released version, not the unstable one. Would I be getting any unwanted side effects from this version naming scheme?